# C / C++ Get MAC Address of a TCP/UDP Server host?

Tags: sockets, tcp, udp, wifi, mac-address

Is there a way to obtain the MAC address of a TCP/UDP server just by looking at the headers or payloads returned back from a network request?

I'm just starting with socket programming and trying to figure out a way to examine a network packet to figure out the MAC addresses of devices a request originated from. Even the 'last wifi device pinged' will be a great starting point.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you just decode the output from "arp -a", is that enough? (only for broadcast media though, and only for immediate neighbours, not routed/bridged etc)

Comment: Why you need the MAC address at all? They're not very useful things, except to network layers. They're aren't reliable as unique system identifiers for example.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get MAC address if server and you are not in the same network.

Why possibly you might need it?

Comment: What if the client side code lived on the server and it pinged itself somehow?

Comment: I need it because the server I'm using does not have programmatic access to the MAC address. Which is why I'm trying to write some code to ping itself and obtain it somehow via the network header packets returned.